# WebSockets with Sencha Touch and Ext JS

Tags: extjs, websocket, extjs4

Is anybody able to provide me some help with using WebSockets with Sencha Touch and Ext JS ideally using the Sencha proxy/store classes or any libraries based on them?

Specifically, is there any direct support for Websockets in Sencha ExtJS and Touch that works with their proxy or store classes?
Otherwise, is there a party-party or open-source plugin that does this?
I need to be able to do Sencha Desktop and Mobile client front-ends and communicate with an application server/webserver in a language such as Erlang.

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - your question is too broad.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try to focus my question better: Is there any direct support for Websockets in Sencha ExtJS and Touch that works with their proxy or store classes? Otherwise is there a party-party or open-source plugin that does this? Specifically I need to be able to do Sencha Desktop and Mobile client front-ends and communicate with an application server/webserver in a language such as Erlang. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Sencha Market](https://market.sencha.com/extensions/ext-ux-data-proxy-websocket). There is a community-built proxy for both Touch and Ext JS.

Comment: Now that Sencha Market is dead does anyone have any info on this?